# Android filling a bar with sliding the entire adaptor view

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making an android app.

I made an adaptor to make a list of views include an imageview and a textview first. 
(I attached URL below here)

I would like to make the bar at the bottom of each adaptor fill in the color when I slide the entire view area.

I don't know how, so I attached a seekbar at the bottom.

But I could only fill the color of the bar when I touch the bar area.

And as you see at the screenshot, there's an afterimage when I slide the bar area.

How do I fill in the color when I touch the entire adapter view area?

And I'd also like to make the bar with no padding. (I made all padding parameter as 0dp, but it still has space in between as you see in the screenshot)

Thank you in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_habit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_tool"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/habit_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:textColor="#3F4047"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="A"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/habit_status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="done"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout_habit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:thumb="@null"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:splitTrack="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

- Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW2hx.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Honestly Im not exactly sure if I understand you correctly. However did you try https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar? With that you can just add a field `progress` to your item model, and in List adapter do something like `progressBar.setProgress(item.progress)`. 
To update progress state just change value of `progress` in item model and update the list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to fill the bar with sliding the whole adapter area. not just touching the bar. Is it possible to make the adapter touchable and update the value of the bar? As you can see on a screenshot, an adaptor includes an imageview, 2 textview, and a bar at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```
seekBar.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

make it programatically in your adapter class